# MarkLogic search documents have properties

Tags: marklogic

How do I search collections to know which uri have properties and only display a list of uri have properties. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a lookup in the URI lexicon with `cts:uris()` with a `cts:true-query()` on the properties fragment should do the trick:

```
cts:uris((), (), cts:properties-fragment-query(cts:true-query()))
```

HTH!